# bib-style format for bibtext bst file- explained by an example

Tags: latex, bibtex

my question is regarding the way a bibtex-style field is defined in a bst file. I would like to have the following example below explained piece by piece, to understand what each piece is doing. I would like to be in a position to make changes to that example myself.

```
FUNCTION {format.eprint}
{ eprint duplicate$ empty$
    'skip$
    { "\eprint"
      archive empty$
        'skip$
        { "[" * archive * "]" * }
      if$
      "{" * swap$ * "}" *
    }
  if$
}
```

Comment: This might be a good question for http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Before you dive into "Tame the BEaST", which is a super smart book, you may want to check out this: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib -- you just run `latex makebst.tex`, complete the long, long survey, and there you are, with a custom `.bst` which mostly works (it did ALMOST everything, removing brackets around year was easy enough to do by hand in my case). Then, learning to code in reverse Polish notation will be left for another time ;)

Answer (score 49):

The BibTeX language is a bit complex: for a full reference take a look at [*Tame the BeaST*](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf). The key things to remember are that it is a stack language and that it uses a postfix approach. Almost all of the built-in functions also remove their input from the stack.

Taking it piece by piece, the first line starts with `FUNCTION`, which means it will define a new function (`format.eprint`) that can be used elsewhere in the `.bst` file. Importantly, this new function can only be used below here: the order of functions in the `.bst` file *is important*. The braces are used to show different arguments: `FUNCTION` needs two, the name of the function and the code that implements it.

In the code itself, `eprint` will be a field. Using the name of a field adds the value of the field to the stack (for the current record). We then have `duplicate$`, which duplicates the top item on the stack. This is a BibTeX build-in instruction, shown by the terminal `$`. So the stack will now contain two copies of the value of `eprint`.

The next instruction is `empty$`. This will test if the top item of the stack is empty *and deletes it*, hence the need for the `duplicate$`. The result of the test is either `1` or `0`, which is left on the stack. So the top item on the stack is now either 1 or 0, and the next item is the value of `eprint`.

Next you have an `if$` statement, which is in postfix and so has the two branches *before* the `if$`. As the language is postfix, what happens is that the `if$` will select the true branch if the top item on the stack is `1` and the false branch otherwise. That also removes the top item from the stack. (If you want the real detail, the two branches are actually placed on the stack, and the `if$` statement then removes the appropriate one and leaves the rest of the material to be executed.)

The first (true) branch reads `'skip$`, which is a 'do nothing' instruction. The braces around a single instruction can be missed out if you include the leading `'`. An alternative which is (slightly) easier to read for new users would be

```
FUNCTION {format.eprint}
{ eprint duplicate$ empty$
    { }
    { "\eprint"
      archive empty$
        { }
        { "[" * archive * "]" * }
      if$
      "{" * swap$ * "}" *
    }
  if$
}
```

*i.e.* simply using an empty set of braces for the 'do nothing' (true) branch. So the aim here is to do nothing if the `eprint` field was empty.

The false branch starts `"\eprint"`, which will place the literal `\eprint` onto the top of the stack. The next part them places the `archive` field onto the stack and does another test for an empty field. If the `archive` field is available, the code

```
"[" * archive * "]" *
```

will place `[` onto the stack then join it to the top item on the stack (which was `\eprint`): this joining operation is what `*` does. The value of the `archive` field is then added to the stack and joined on, followed by another `]`. So the top of the stack will contain

```
\eprint[<archive>]
```

(where `<archive>` is the value of the archive field) if there is anything given for `archive`, and still just `\eprint` otherwise.

Finally, there is some more string-building to do. We have

```
"{" * swap$ * "}" *
```

which first places `{` onto the stack. This is joined onto the top item (`\eprint` or `\eprint[<archive>]`) to give `\eprint{`. The `swap$` function swaps the top two items on the stack, so the top item is name `<eprint>` (the value of the `eprint` field). There is a joint to make

```
\eprint{<eprint>
```

followed by a final addition of `}` to the end.

The result is that the stack will gain one item on the top. If `eprint` is empty there will be an empty item on the top of the stack, otherwise it will read

```
    \eprint{<eprint>}
```